# What are dpuf (extension) files?

Tags: html

I have seen this extension in some urls and I would like to know what they are used for.
It seems odd, but I couldn't find any information about them. I think they are specific for some plug-in.

Comment: See this http://www.bloggerhero.com/2013/07/remove-sharethis-sthash-tag-ending-with-url.html

Comment: File name extensions are overrated anyways. Detecting a files content type by looking at the "extension" shown in the file name is an approach from the medieval times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be connected to 'Share This'-buttons on the websites.

I found this [page](http://www.bloggerhero.com/2013/07/remove-sharethis-sthash-tag-ending-with-url.html) which gives a quite comprehensive explanation:

> This tag is mainly developed for tracking the URL sharing on various Social Networks, so every time anyone copies your blog content there he gets the URL ending with #sthash and extension with .dpuf or .dpbs